# how to add a final approval step to a docusign document

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using the C# docusign.eSign package.  I have a word document that has some  anchor text for people to sign the document, this works fine, it adds the signers at the correct spots.

I want to add a final approver step.  where a certain user would view the document in docusign and approve it (presumably its an Approve Tab).  We do not want extra text on the document, but need a log that they viewed and approved it, and when.

```
var recipients = new Recipients { Signers = new List<Signer>() };
int recipientIndex = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < request.Signers.Count; i++)
{
    var signerDetails = request.Signers[i];

    SignHere[] signHereTabs =
    {
        new SignHere
        {
            RecipientId = $"{recipientIndex}",
            AnchorString = signerDetails.SignatureAnchorText,
            AnchorXOffset = "0",
            AnchorYOffset = "0.5",
            AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
            AnchorUnits = "inches"
        }
    };

    var signer = new Signer
    {
        Email = signerDetails.EmailAddress,
        Name = signerDetails.Name,
        ClientUserId = GetClientId(signerDetails.Id),
        RecipientId = $"{recipientIndex}",
        Tabs = new Tabs { SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>(signHereTabs),  }
    };

    recipients.Signers.Add(signer);
    recipientIndex++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < request.Approvers.Count; i++)
{
    var appoverDetails = request.Approvers[i];
    var approverHereTabs = new Approve[]
    {
        new Approve
        {
            RecipientId = $"{recipientIndex}",
            XPosition = "2",
            YPosition = "2",
        }
    };
    var approver = new Signer
    {
        Email = appoverDetails.EmailAddress,
        Name = appoverDetails.Name,
        ClientUserId = GetClientId(appoverDetails.Id),
        RecipientId = $"{recipientIndex}",
        Tabs = new Tabs { ApproveTabs = new List<Approve>(approverHereTabs), }
    };

    recipients.Signers.Add(approver);
    recipientIndex++;
}
```

```
var envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
            {
                EmailSubject = request.Title.ToTruncatedValue(100),
                Documents = new List<Document> { doc },
                Recipients = recipients,
                Status = "sent"
            };
```

I new up an instance of the API client

```
var apiClient = new ApiClient(
                configuration.UseLiveSystem
                    ? ApiClient.Production_REST_BasePath
                    : ApiClient.Demo_REST_BasePath);
```

create an access token from a refresh token.

```
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);

EnvelopeSummary results = null;

            try
            {
                results = await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(configuration.AccountId, envelopeDefinition);
            }
            catch (ApiException e)
            {
                if (e.Message.Contains("USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT"))
                {
                    throw new CodwellersException(
                        DocumentSigningServiceExceptionType.DocuSignPermissionNotGiven);
                }

                if (e.Message.Contains("USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"))
                {
                    throw new CodwellersException(
                        DocumentSigningServiceExceptionType.DocuSignFault);
                }

                throw;
            }
```

My guess was to add the approve tab above and se the x and y position to be at the top of the document.  This didn't seem to add anything.

I can't find any documentation as to how these are supposed to work.

Comment: Have not worked with docusign but... Isn't strange that all the `Approve[]` items do share the same coordinates (x = 2, Y = 2)?

Comment: @Cleptus yes, that was just for testing, as currently only have one approver. would update that to something more meaningful once I get the basics working

Comment: how do you actually create the envelope? can you share your full code?

Comment: @InbarGazit updated with the basics of the envelope and client (had to try and simplify it as it is somewhat abstracted with configuration and bits like that)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `DocumentId` and `PageNumber` in the `Approve tab`, DocuSign has to know which document to put it on and what page in this document if you don't use anchor strings.

Comment: I have not needed these in the signers (which works), so my assumption was they are not required.  I had also tried to use `AnchorString` without success

Comment: These are two completely different things. If you use AnchorSting - you don't need to specify as DocuSign will scan all pages of all documents.

Answer (score 0):

approving and signing are basically the same thing in docusign.  approving just doesn't put anything on the page (still goes in the logs as a signature).

The issue turned out to be the anchorstring has to have white space around it, I had not noticed it was butting up against other text, so it wasn't finding the string to match against.